Does nucleosynthesis such as R Process, S Process, and P process occur in relativistic jets?
By answering a recent question about relativistic jets and their cooling I became more curious about relativistic jets. This might be a totally another sub topic on relativistic jets. But I was wondering could nucleosynthesis occur in relativistic jets? A couple of research papers show that it could occur but I wonder if they are verified (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008ApJ...680.1350F/abstract). This research paper particullarly states collapsors which are different from black holes but I might wonder if it is the same case for relativistic jets.

Your linked article is about relativistic jets internal to collapsing stars, where the density is high enough for nucleosynthesis to proceed. This cannot be observed directly. Without such observations, this model is difficult to verify.

+1. Nice answer. Just need to ask 1 thing: Even if it is unobservable, is it theoretically possible? and if so what are the challenges?

Theoretically possible? I think so. The challenge with supernovae is that the star blows up and leaves little evidence of what was going on inside it.

Thanks for the answer
